# jQuery Addition

Tags: jquery, addition

I'm attempting to add 2 values together with jQuery.  I have a table with these values:

```
<table>
<tr id="fc_cart_foot_subtotal">
<td class="fc_col2">$7.95</td>
</tr>
<tr id="fc_cart_foot_shipping">
<td class="fc_col2">$4.00</td>
</tr>
<tr id="fc_cart_foot_total">
<td class="fc_col2">$7.95</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to add the value of #fc_cart_foot_subtotal .fc_col2:

```
<tr id="fc_cart_foot_subtotal">
<td class="fc_col2">$7.95</td>
</tr>
```

to the value of #fc_cart_foot_shipping .fc_col2:

```
<tr id="fc_cart_foot_shipping">
<td class="fc_col2">$4.00</td>
</tr>
```

and have the value of #fc_cart_foot_total .fc_col2 updated

```
<tr id="fc_cart_foot_total">
<td class="fc_col2">$7.95</td>
</tr>
```

So in this example, the first subtotal value of $7.95 should add $4.00 to give a total of $11.95.  The subtotal and shipping cost will change, so I'll need to be able to "grab" those values as they change and use them in an equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the dollar string into a number for addition:

```
function parseDollar(str) {
   return +str.substr(1);
}
```

Then to add the numbers together and format it correctly:

```
$('#fc_cart_foot_total .fc_col2').text('$' + (
    parseDollar($('#fc_cart_foot_subtotal .fc_col2').text()) +
    parseDollar($('#fc_cart_foot_shipping .fc_col2').text())
).toFixed(2));
```

If it is possible that you can get negative dollar values e.g. "-$1.00", then change `parseDollar` to:

```
function parseDollar(str) {
    return +str.replace(/\$/, '');
}
```

Comment: very cool.  this works!  my only question: in the result, the "$" has disappeared.  How do I add that in to get "$11.95" versus "11.95"?

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  I see you updated your code.  That put the "$" back in.  Awesome!